# Data Replication/Integration for SFDC Formula Fields

Tags: integration, formula-field, informatica

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

We have an integration stack/replication batch (Informatica) that copies all of our data from SFDC. The change data capture process is based off of SFDC's LastModifiedDate and SystemModStamp.

Our problem: Formula fields only generate their values at run-time/query-time, and in addition, do not change SFDC LastModifiedDate/SystemModStamp. In that case, our change data capture process does not know the record changed and will not pick it up in it's daily batch for refresh.

There are millions of records in the system, so a full refresh each day is not possible. Anyone know any workarounds with this or experience the same issue?

Regards,
J Ramirez

Comment: What do you mean by "all of our data from SFDC"? Is that from single object or multiple objects?

Comment: As formula fields can vary in value based on time or changes in values of fields in related objects, this is a hard problem in general

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the suggested solution using Workato can actually help. The problem as described is getting the updated value of the formula field. **Sadly though formula fields are not stored as data in Salesforce and generated at runtime.**

The 'trigger' as described in Workato recipes is fired when the record is updated. In this case however, even though the value of the formula field is being captured at Runtime, the record never gets updated. Hence there's no change to the LastModified or the SystemModified stamps.

The easiest and possibly the lamest way I can think around is storing the formula field values some custom field. I'll look out for a better solution though.